# Calculating Sample size of a linear regression

Tags: regression, statistical-power

I just would like if anyone knows how to calculate the sample size for the data set given the significance level is set at alpha = 0.05 and the power of the test should be 80%. The linear regression is as follows. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)
z1 = rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.2)
z2 = rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.2)+1
epsilon <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 3)
y = 3 + 5*x1 - x2 + 0.25*z1 + 4*z2 + epsilon
```

Comment: Have you tried running a simulation to find the answer? (increase by steps n until you satisfy the constraints)

Comment: *Which* test are you referring to?  In this model, at least *five* different tests will automatically be conducted and reported by most statistical software.

Comment: I am using R to run the simulations but I don't know the codes on how can I set the power of the regression coefficient of x2 to 0.8 while the power of the other regression coefficients of other predictor variables remains untouched.

Comment: The calculation of sample size should be based on simulations and not on formula.

Comment: Either you need historical data to get the variance or to run simulations..